# XSLT: Override fn:generate-id function to create a predictable result using Saxon

Tags: xslt, saxon

We depend on an external XSLT library that is out of our control.  There are some `fn:generate-id` calls in this library and it is causing results to be different every time we run it.

We are using Saxon 10.5 (Java).  Is there a way to override or configure the `fn:generate-id` call so it will produce predictable results, while preserving the node uniqueness?

Comment: I don't think `generate-id()` is supposed to return the same value on different runs. If you need that in XSLT 3 perhaps use an accumulator counting nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could post-process the output to replace the IDs with ones that you generate yourself, or you could change the stylesheet logic to use xsl:number (or an accumulator function) instead.

In extremis, you could define your own implementation of the Saxon NodeInfo interface (perhaps subclassing an existing implementation), in which case you have full control of the generateId algorithm, but that's getting into some pretty deep water.

In fact, at least for the TinyTree model, Saxon generates the ID in two parts: a document number, and a node-number within the document. If the document doesn't change, then the second part shouldn't change. You could post-process the result to strip out the document number. But of course you have then introduced a dependency into your application, you're assuming Saxon won't change its strategy.

Comment: var config = new Configuration();

config.setDocumentNumberAllocator(new NonIncrementingDocumentNumberAllocator());

var xsltFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl(config);


The NonIncrementingDocumentNumberAllocator just returns 0 from its methods.  This has made the generate-id() function calls stable.  Are there any side-effects to consider?

Comment: Yes, anything that depends on document order or testing nodes for identity is going to be completely messed up.

Comment: Read the Javadoc: The document number allocator is used to allocate a unique number to each document built under this configuration. The document number forms the basis of all tests for node identity; it is therefore essential that when two documents are accessed in the same XPath expression, they have distinct document numbers. Normally this is ensured by building them under the same Configuration. Using this method together with {@link #setDocumentNumberAllocator}, however, it is possible to have two different Configurations that share a single DocumentNumberAllocator